# How do I hide the textfield cursor on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cursor, textfield

How do I hide the textfield cursor on the iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean hiding the cursor (and the keyboard) when the user is done typing? If not, why would you want to hide the cursor when the user is still in typing mode?

Comment: @mihirsm : i had resolved. Thank you for your help and kindness.

Comment: Can please share how you have resolved this issue?

Comment: If you are trying to implement a pin control, then you definitely want to hide the cursor while the user is typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this...

```
[currentlySelectedTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

This will cause a text field to lose focus and the keyboard to hide again.

If you want to hide the blinking cursor line... I don't think you can do that easily.